# Query XML file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I was using simple sql table and procedures to bind my DropDownlist, but it seems that it is taking some time load the items in the list.. So now I am trying to bind my DropDownList with XML file file which has the data I want to bind my DropDownList with..

**MY CODE**

```
 XElement main = XElement.Load(filePath);
        IEnumerable<XElement> searched =
            from c in main.Elements("GLCODE")
            where (string)c.Element("GLCODEITEM").Attribute("PostingGL") == "200142"
            select c;
        DropDownList1.DataSource = searched;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "GL";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "PostingGL";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

**MY XML**

```
<GLCODE>
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200085</PostingGL>
    <GL>200085 - Bank charges</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200089</PostingGL>
    <GL>200089 - ROC FEES</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200098</PostingGL>
    <GL>200098 - STAMP DUTY CHARGES</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>      
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200130</PostingGL>
    <GL>200130 - Consumables - Backup Tapes</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200130</PostingGL>
    <GL>200130 - Consumables - Miscellaneous</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200133</PostingGL>
    <GL>200133 - ELECTRICITY EXPENSES</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>      
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200140</PostingGL>
    <GL>200140 - PROFESSION TAX - COMPANY</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>
  <GLCODEITEM>
    <PostingGL>200142</PostingGL>
    <GL>200142 - REPAIRS AND MAINTENANC</GL>
  </GLCODEITEM>
</GLCODE>
```

The problem is that I am not getting anything value in my DropDownList.
Can someone please teach me some simple way to query XML and such as 
SELECT name,phoneno FROM Table WHERE Country="abc"

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");
var addresses = from address in xelement.Elements("GLCODE")
                where (string)address.Element("GLCODEITEM").Element("PostingGL") == "20014"
               select address;
foreach (XElement xEle in address)
{

}
```